# Printing only some elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to ask you guys how can i print a two-dimensional array so it can look like a chessboard and to print only the numbers that are on the white.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the amount of rows: "<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Enter the amount of columns: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    if(!cin){
        cout<<"Error.Bad input."<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    double arr[m][n];
    cout<<"Enter the element of the array: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int x = 0;x<n;x++){
        cin>>arr[i][x];
    }
    }
    cout<<"Printed array like a chessboard: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++){
        cout<<arr[i][x]<<" ";
        }cout<<endl;
    }

}
```

If i enter for example 4 rows and 4 columns and i enter the following numbers so it can be printed out like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I want an output like this:

```
1 3
6 8
9 11
14 16
```

Thanks is advance!

Comment: this is unrelated to the question, and correct me if i'm wrong, but my understanding of c++ is that you cannot assign the size of an array with a post-compile time variable, ie the compiler needs to know what the size of the array is before compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all take into account that there are no Variable Length Arrays (VLA) in C++. So your code might not be compiled using some other compiler.

The task you are trying to do can be done very simply.:)

Just write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
{
    for ( int x = i % 2; x < n; x += 2) cout << arr[i][x] <<" ";
                  ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a nested loop to only print when i + x is even:

```
 for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int x = 0;x<n;x++){
     if ((i + x) % 2 == 0)
        cout<<arr[i][x];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for loop for printing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i += 2){
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x += 2){
        cout << arr[i][x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int x = 1; x < n; x += 2){
        cout << arr[i + 1][x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This way `x` index advances by 2 in each iteration. And starts at different index 0 or 1 for each row

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! But I've done that and it prints 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15 when i want 1,3,6,8,9,11,14,16 which represent the "white" squares.

Comment: it needed one more edit to `cout << endl;` now it produces the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Check in every cell the "rank" of index with modulo:

```
if((x+i)%2 == 0)
```

Then print out, he value when evaluates true.

Lasoloz